# creating a RadioButton style with image by binding source

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

C# (& WPF) noob here trying to learn by making

I´m currently trying to make a GUI using WPF for a personal project based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzP8mw7JUzI)

```xml
<!-- Top bar and main window -->
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid>
        <!-- Top bar with close, maximize and minimize -->
    </Grid>

    <!-- Navigation panel and main view -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Navigation panel -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="navigation_panel">

            <RadioButton Content="Menu"
                         Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"/>
            
            <!-- Adding more buttons to the menu -->

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

As a MenuButtonTheme I have:

```xml
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
        TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"
        x:Key="MenuButtonTheme">
        
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                        <Image Source="..\Icons\menu.png"
                                Margin="20,0,20,0"
                                Width="30" Height="30"/>
                        
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    </Style.Setters>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#22202f"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#333345"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The idea was to have a radio button and then have the style create the stackPanel with the image and text.

Everything works, however, as I'm doing with the content field, passing the string I want the style to show, I also wanted to set the image source. In order to select different logos for each radioButton.

But the radioButton has no Source property.

Is there a field I can use to pass this kind of information? Is this the correct way of doing this?

Sorry if it's an easy to find solution, but either I can't find or I don't know what I'm looking for. All I find is how to make the icon changed based on the isChecked property.
But that's not what I'm looking for (I think)

**edit:**

The main idea was to be able to do this in the theme:

```xml
...
   <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Property=Source}"
          Margin="20,0,20,0"
          Width="30" Height="30"/>
...
```

and adding the RadioButton like this:

```xml
...
   <RadioButton Content="Menu"
                Source="path\to\image.png"
                Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"/>
```

The image component has a Source property, but as I'm basing the style on a ToggleButton, I can't have the binding to that property

Comment: What do you you mean by saying "the radio Button has no Source property".   Are you talking about the Binding source?  That's the `DataContext` if you do not specify one explicitly in the `Binding`.  If you do not give a `RadioButton` a `DataContext`, it will inherit that of its parent.  Or are you saying that should each radio button have a *different* `DataContext`?  If that's the case -- if you are binding against a collection of objects, then you should use some form of `ItemsControl` with `ItemsSource` bound to that collection of objects.  Like a `ListBox`, for example

Comment: I edited the question so it shows what I intend to do, hope this helps clarify?

Comment: You could use the `Tag` Property to store the value.  It's intended for any use you want.  But the "proper" way to do this is to take the set of properties that each `RadioButton` needs and put them into a view-model class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Put all the instances of this class you'll need into a list (or an `ObservableCollection` if the buttons might change).  Then use an `ItemsControl` and bind its ItemsSource to this collection.  Finally set the `ItemTemplate` of the ItemsControl to be your `StackPanel`  Its `DataContext` will be your object, to bind against.

Comment: If everything will be static and unchanging you do not need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the class that holds your button info.